# How to create Kubeflow pipeline to take images and annotations from GSBucket, train model and store it to GS Bucket in python?

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

Hello I am a newbie in Kubeflow and Kubernetes.
I have 100 images and its annotations in a GS Bucket. I want to build a Kubeflow pipeline to access those 100 images and its annotations, then using them I should be able to run my training python file. After that, I have to store the model in another GS Bucket. I have seen few videos, but I am not able to draw a clear picture.
How do I prepare such a pipe line ? What all things do I need to do to prepare it ?
Any pointer or reference will be very helpful.
Thanks.